# Is there any Limitation to display huge number of rows/no of columns using tableviewer swt/jface

Tags: eclipse, swt, jface

In my own eclipse product, I am trying to load more number of rows to  display in table. I am using jface tableviewer. I am getting swt handlers error when retrieving the data . Is there any limitation to display number of rows with jface tableviewer?

I am using configurations like  eclipse 4.14 , windows 10 ,OpenJdk 11
Here is some piece of code that how i proceed
we are using excel to load the data in table format 
In that excel , we have 225 columns and 15rows . I am attaching the
corresponding excel

We are importing the excel sheet data with  225 columns as rows in the
table format with 7 column headers like below

For this, we are using jface tableviewer

```
  TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.HIDE_SELECTION);
    table = viewer.getTable();
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(false);
    table.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    String[] columnNames = new String[8];
    GridLayout tableLayout = new GridLayout();
    tableLayout.marginTop = 30;
    tableLayout.verticalSpacing = 5;
    table.setLayout(tableLayout);
```

and for column headers we are creating for each columns like below

```
TableViewerColumn upDownColumn = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
upDownColumn.getColumn().setText(UP_DOWN);
upDownColumn.getColumn().setWidth(130);
upDownColumn.getColumn().setResizable(false);
```

and to set the label provider for each column, we are creating the
renderers  based on table  like below

```
CustomLabelControlRenderer renderer = PropertySheetUtil. 
createRenderer(CustomLabelControlRenderer.class, table,setting, 
null);          
columnNames[0] = UP_DOWN;
```

like above , we are creating 7 column headers
After creating column headers, we are setting the input like

```
    viewer.setColumnProperties(columnNames);
    viewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
    viewer.setUseHashlookup(true);
    viewer.setInput(fieldList);
    table.getVerticalBar().setVisible(true)
```

The screenshot of my table like below
[image]

and we are getting error in the console like below
    !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2020-01-23 12:39:47.303
 !MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
    !STACK 0
    org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4737)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4626)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4597)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createHandle(Control.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.createHandle(Composite.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createWidget(Control.java:761)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.createWidget(Scrollable.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.(Control.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.(Scrollable.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.(Composite.java:99)
    at com.spacetimeinsight.sistudio.datasource.renderers.DataSourceFieldsRenderer$6.update(DataSourceFieldsRenderer.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerColumn.refresh(ViewerColumn.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTableViewer.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(StructuredViewer.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil.lambda$0(JFaceUtil.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateItem(StructuredViewer.java:2097)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.createItem(AbstractTableViewer.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefreshAll(AbstractTableViewer.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTableViewer.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTableViewer.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.lambda$0(AbstractTableViewer.java:572)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1393)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1354)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.inputChanged(AbstractTableViewer.java:572)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.setInput(ContentViewer.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setInput(StructuredViewer.java:1627)
    at com.spacetimeinsight.sistudio.datasource.renderers.DataSourceFieldsRenderer.createCustomSwtControl(DataSourceFieldsRenderer.java:536)
    at com.spacetimeinsight.sistudio.core.propertysheet.AbstractBaseControlRenderer.createSWTControl(AbstractBaseControlRenderer.java:449)
    at com.spacetimeinsight.sistudio.core.propertysheet.AbstractBaseControlRenderer.initControl(AbstractBaseControlRenderer.java:270)
    at com.spacetimeinsight.sistudio.ui.datasource.DataSourceComponentSection.createTableImportDataSource(DataSourceComponentSection.java:490)
    at com.spacetimeinsight.sistudio.ui.datasource.DataSourceComponentSection.shouldRadioGroupCreated(DataSourceComponentSection.java:215)
    at com.spacetimeinsight.sistudio.ui.datasource.DataSourceComponentSection.createControls(DataSourceComponentSection.java:149)
    at com.spacetimeinsight.sistudio.datasource.AbstractDataSourceType.createControls(AbstractDataSourceType.java:292)
    at com.spacetimeinsight.sistudio.ui.datasource.DataSourceFieldPropertySection.updateControls(DataSourceFieldPropertySection.java:48)
    at com.spacetimeinsight.sistudio.core.propertysheet.CustomPropertySection.setInput(CustomPropertySection.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed.TabContents$5.run(TabContents.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil.lambda$0(JFaceUtil.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed.TabContents.setInput(TabContents.java:187)
    at com.spacetimeinsight.sistudio.ui.common.tabbed.CustomTabbedPropertySheetPage$SelectionChangedListener.selectionChanged(CustomTabbedPropertySheetPage.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$1.run(Viewer.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil.lambda$0(JFaceUtil.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2118)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1170)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1199)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$4(OpenStrategy.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4173)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1081)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:780)
    at com.spacetimeinsight.sistudio.ui.common.tabbed.CustomTabbedPropertyList.select(CustomTabbedPropertyList.java:913)
    at com.spacetimeinsight.sistudio.ui.common.tabbed.CustomTabbedPropertyList$ListElement$2.mouseUp(CustomTabbedPropertyList.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4173)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3986)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3585)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1049)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at
    org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:660)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1468)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1441)
    !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2020-01-23 12:39:47.306
    !MESSAGE Error occurred during status handling
    !STACK 0
    org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4737)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4626)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4597)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createHandle(Control.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.createHandle(Composite.java:295)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.createHandle(Decorations.java:378)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.createHandle(Shell.java:595)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createWidget(Control.java:761)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.createWidget(Scrollable.java:154)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.createWidget(Decorations.java:387)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.(Shell.java:302)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.(Shell.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.createShell(Window.java:487)
        at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:430)
        at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1094)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.doAddStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.java:248)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.addStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.java:189)
        at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManager.addStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManager.java:152)
        at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler.showStatusAdapter(WorkbenchErrorHandler.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler.handle(WorkbenchErrorHandler.java:52)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.handle(IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchErrorHandlerProxy.handle(WorkbenchErrorHandlerProxy.java:34)
        at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:256)
        at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:266)
        at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.eventLoopException(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:325)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$1.eventLoopException(Workbench.java:486)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.handle(PartRenderingEngine.java:1180)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1170)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1049)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:633)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:557)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:660)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1468)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1441)

Comment: I used SWT.VIRUTUAL and implements lazycontentprovider but i am not able to see the data even scrolling also

Comment: I have edited my question and the error which i am getting. I am unable to take out sample code to reproduce . May i know the root cause for getting swt handle errors?

Comment: R u saying about SWT.VIRTUAL?